# How to rename a copied file without renaming the original

Tags: linux, bash

I copy the files in my home directory to a new directory. When I attempt to rename a file in this new directory, the file in the home directory is changed and the file in the new directory retains its name. My code is shown below.

```
srcDir=$HOME
newDir=$1
mkdir $1

cp $srcDir/* $newDir

for file in newDir/*; do
    filename=$(basename $file)
    if [[ SOMETHING ]]; then
        mv $filename newname
    fi
done
```

If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using [git](http://git-scm.com/) for your source code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are renaming files in the current working directory, as with

```
mv ./$filename newname
```

You need to prepend the path:

```
mv newDir/"$filename" newDir/newname
```

Or, change the working directory:

```
cd newDir
for file in * ; do
    mv "$file" newname
done
```

Comment: Thank for your help! For the prepend solution, what purpose do the quotation marks serve?

Comment: @AndréFoote: Without double quotes, you can't work with filenames containing spaces and other special characters.